# Omni-Channel Offline Agents not visible when supervisor configuration is set

Tags: servicecloud, omni-supervisor

As per documentation to see offline agents in supervisor tab, Service Resource must be shared with the supervisor:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_show_offline_agents_in_supervisor.htm&type=5

**Once Omni-Channel Supervisor Configurations is assigned to the supervisor offline agents are no longer visible.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Public Group cannot contain Role and Subordinates. You must exactly specify users in order to appear them in Omni Supervisor tab when they are offline.

Comment: Try this solution: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2022/08/offline-agents-are-unavailable-in-the-agent-summary-of-salesforce-omni-supervisor.html